# Facebook API page feed didn't send information to my webhook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks, facebook-feed

I'm admin of my test app, and my test page.

Now I'm doing a function get page's feed realtime by webhook, just only on development mode.

When I click test button on App's Dashboard, It has been sent to my webhook. But when I comment or like ... the post, facebook doesn't send even though I subscribed feed webhook.
With Messages, it has been sent successfully, but Feed doesn't.

I ask facebook support, so they said that:

> "Applications will only be able to receive test webhooks sent from the
>   app dashboard while they are in development. No production data,
>   including that of app admins, developers, and testers, will be
>   delivered unless the app is live. In order to receive feed webhooks,
>   your app needs to be live and has to go through app review for
>   necessary permissions."

I understand that I can not get data from facebook even though it is under development mode.
So how can I get data returned by facebook to develop, test... apps in development mode.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you got the resolution to your problem lately ? I have been struggling through this long back.. getting my App Reviewed is becoming pain as i cannot develop and send for review with limited permissions. @Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to run this service without an app review, since it is not possible to add the 'mange_pages' permission to a ([test-](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users))user within a development app. At the same time it is not possible to turn a testapp into live-mode. As the same is true vice versa the only solution is the app review to get information from a specific ([test-](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages/))page.

- For live testing i suggest to create a [testuser](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) and subscribe for information about the "user" to test your webhook.
- You can check with `GET graph.facebook.com/app-id/subscriptions`, if your app is successfully subscribed to "page information". [Graph API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/subscriptions-edge)
- As you already mentioned you can also send "page information" test calls to your endpoint.

**UPDATE 18th Nov 2018**

[image]

If you go to Webhook -> pages in your App Dashboard on https://developers.facebook.com you are able to notice, that Webhooks in dev mode do not work.

Comment: I don't quite follow the setup to receive page webhook and be able to post comments.
The case scenario would be :
 - User post a comment on the page (need to receive webhook from page)
 - Page reply to the post as a comment (need publish_pages permissions)

Comment: Any solution to this? I have subscribed app to Test page with webhook page>feed subscribed. it's in development mode I can get test call from the dashboard but still can't receive updates from Test user and Test page.

Comment: @RemyBurney did you get the Facebook reviews from webhooks?

Comment: @ManeeshRao, no I did not. I put this project in the backlog hopping you would have the solution ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I've submitted a Bug report to Facebook for this issue, as there is no proper solution.
You can check it at : https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1570460936387604/

I also don't get the fact that you can't test webhooks in dev mode, and you can't do the app review because you can't develop your app and show them for review.
Just a chicken and egg issue.

Comment: Yes, that's a chicken and egg issue. We can't develop app. But now facebook don't have suggestion to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to test getting my Graph API working for the /feed/ endpoint.

1. You must set your app to 'live'
2. if you have a business manager, the app must be registered in the BM
3. the user must have a role in the app assigned
4. and lastly, where I was stuck - the Page must have the app subscribed to the page. You can run this via the  Graph API explorer to subscribe the app to the page.

This finally allowed me to post on my page, and trigger my server API call for the action. Hope this helps someone - spent a couple hours trying to figure this out.

[webhook for pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/webhooks-for-pages/)