# How do I get real-time facebook page feed in my webhook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time, facebook-webhooks, facebook-feed

I subscribed my page with feed event in pages webhook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime/).

Also, setup the apps webhook product with feed subscribe and changed the domain name as webhook domain name. We have "manage_pages" permission on our app and our app is now live mode. I tried every possible way that I know and got after googling. But I couldn't receive facebook page feed real-time data in my webhook. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks so much.

**Note:** I tried before posting this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039198/5695622 with the test user. But didn't get the real-time facebook page feed on my webhook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the "Ngrok", that's why I didn't get the real-time facebook feed data. After chatting with facebook support they fix the problem.
[Here is the facebook support link](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/345033839769302/)

[image]